# Not able to view the textview inside linearlayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written a simple program to get familiar with the UI design in android. I have dynamically added texts inside a linear layout. When i debug the code i'm not able to see any error in the logcat, the code runs perfectly well. But i'm not able to see any text in my device. I'm using Galaxy S2.I have tried using the emulator also. But nothing showed up. I don't have an idea why it is not showing any text in my device/emulator. Please help.

Here is my activity

```
public class ViewActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
LinearLayout bar;
String myarray[]={"Foot Ball","Basket Ball","Cricket"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
bar= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tag);// Map the Layout
bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TextView bs_text[]= new TextView[myarray.length]; // Create TextView according to value in length variable;

for(int z=0;z< myarray.length ;z++)
{
try
{

bs_text[z] = (TextView) new TextView(this);
bs_text[z].setText( myarray [z]);
//bs_text[z].setTextSize(1);
bs_text[z].setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
bs_text[z].setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
int height_in_pixels = bs_text[z].getLineCount() * bs_text[z].getLineHeight(); //approx height text
bs_text[z].setHeight(height_in_pixels);
//bs_text[z].setHeight(android.graphics.)
bar.addView(bs_text[z]);
}

catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
Log.d("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException",e.toString());
}
}
}
    }
```

here is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tag"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi mithu, Let me try this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set layoutparams to the textview as:

```
bs_text[z].setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
bar.addView(bs_text[z],new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the layoutparams to the textview like

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textview.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearView` is probably displayed with `width`=0 and `height`=0 when you first display it:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Since it has no content the size is 0. You should reset the view, something like:

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
bar.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

after you have added the TextViews

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give specific weight to the TextViews, then you can set the layout parameters as following -

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
```

where `1.0f` is the showing the weight of the `TextView`. and then add param to the `TextView`

```
bs_text[z].setLayoutParams(param);
```